# 8-Puzzle BFS output trouble in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search

This is an 8 puzzle and uses bfs and dfs to solve find the solution and prints out the path to the goal. I am having trouble poping and appending the children so that it can find the solution. My error is that it will only print out the two options and does not branch out from the possible solution. The terminal is still going despite not printing out anything.

Here is my code and on the bottom is a test case.

```
import copy

#This is the only file you need to work on. You do NOT need to modify other files

# Below are the functions you need to implement. For the first project, you only need to finish implementing bfs() and dfs()

#here you need to implement the Breadth First Search Method
def bfs(puzzle):
    list = []
    #initialization 
    state = copy.deepcopy(puzzle)
    goal = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    possible_move = [[1,3],[0,2,4],[1,5],[0,4,6],[1,3,5,7],[2,4,8],[3,7],[4,6,8],[5,7]]
    
     #appending the first state 
    queue = []
    queue = [Node(state)]
    
    for node in queue[:]:
      print('the state of this game position is:\n ' + str(node.state))
      loop = True
      notFound = True
      l = 0

    while loop:
        for node in queue:
            #blank index in each state 
            blank = node.state.index(8)
            print('the index of the blank is '+ str(blank))
            #The possible position 
            possible_pos = possible_move[blank]
            print('possible pos '+ str(possible_pos))
            if state != goal:
                for i in possible_pos:
                    possible_sw = copy.deepcopy(node.state)
                    print('index swap = '+ str(i))
                    
                    temp = possible_sw[i]
                    possible_sw[i] = 8
                    possible_sw[blank] = temp
                
                    print('the child nodes is ' + str(possible_sw))
                    node.insertChild(possible_sw)
                    
                    if possible_sw == goal:
                        print('end')
                        notFound = False
                        loop = False
                
    #check each child and find the goal state 
        for node in queue[:]:
            for child_state in node.children:
                if child_state == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]:
                    final_state = child_state
                    print('the final state is '+ str(final_state.state))
            queue.pop(0)
            
        #find the parent path 
        while node.parent and loop is False:
            sol_path = final_state.state
            list.append(sol_path.index(8))
            if final_state.parent is not None:
                final_state = final_state.parent
            else: 
                parent = False
                list.reverse()
                list.pop(0)
                print('moves list '+ str(list))
    
    return list

#here you need to implement the Depth First Search Method
def dfs(puzzle):
    list = []
    return list

#This will be for next project
def astar(puzzle):
    list = []
    return list

def swap(list, pos1, pos2):
    list[pos1],list[pos2] = list[pos2], list[pos1]
    return list
        
class Node:
    def __init__(self,state,parent = None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.state = state
        self.children = []
        
    def insertChild(self, child_state):
        self.children.append(Node(child_state,self))

#test cases 

# p =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 7]
p = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7]
#p = [0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 7, 5]
#p =[0, 4, 1, 3, 8, 2, 6, 7, 5]
bfs(p)
print("+++++++++++++++++++++")
#dfs(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your attempt:

- The queue never receives more entries; `queue.append` is never called. On the other hand, the inner loop over `queue[:]` empties the queue with `pop`, removing its only element. And from that moment on the queue remains empty.
- The `Node` constructor is called only once, so there will never be more than one node, and the test `node.parent` will always be false, making the last `while` loop useless, and the moveslist (if any) will never be printed
- If the end is not found in the first iteration -- meaning the initial position is not one move away from the goal -- the outer loop will get into an infinite loop: on its second iteration the queue is empty, so there is nothing to do, and the `loop` name will never become True.
- `if state != goal` makes little sense as the `state` name never changes in the loop. If anything, this should reference `node.state`, not `state`.
- The `list.pop(0)` at the very end unnecessarily removes a move. The loop condition already checks if the node has a parent -- so skipping the root state -- so then you'll miss *two* states.
- The code does not check whether the *initial* position is maybe the goal position, and so it will not return an empty move list as solution when this is the case.

Some other remarks:

- `swap` is never called.
- The code has several names which serve no purpose, like `l`, `notFound`.
- It uses `list` which is a native name in Python -- choose a different name.
- The `children` attribute of the `Node` instances is not useful. Although you iterate it to find the final state, the logic for identifying whether the goal was reached, is already present elsewhere in the code... it doesn't need `children`.
- `deepcopy` is not needed: the lists you use are not "deep". You can simply copy them by applying the `list` (native) function, or slicing them with `[:]`.
- Assigning twice to `queue` in sequence (in the initialisation) makes the first assignment useless. Just have the second assignment.
- The loop in the initialisation part should not be a loop. At that moment you *know* the queue has only one entry, so iterating it is overkill. You can just output the initial state using `puzzle`. But maybe you wanted to output the state *in the loop*...
- There is no need for `temp` to perform a swap. First of all, Python can do tuple assignment, but also: a move is not *really* a swap of two unknown values: you know that one of the two is the empty cell (8), so you can safely overwrite that cell with the other cell's value, and then set the other cell's value to 8 -- no `temp` is needed.

Here is your code corrected with the above remarks:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,state,parent = None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.state = state


def bfs(puzzle):
    solution = []
    #initialization 
    goal = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    possible_move = [[1,3],[0,2,4],[1,5],[0,4,6],[1,3,5,7],[2,4,8],[3,7],[4,6,8],[5,7]]
    node = Node(puzzle)
    queue = [node]
    
    while True:
        node = queue.pop(0)
        print('the state of this game position is:\n ' + str(node.state))
        if node.state == goal:
            break
        blank = node.state.index(8)
        print('the index of the blank is '+ str(blank))
        possible_pos = possible_move[blank]
        print('possible pos '+ str(possible_pos))
        for i in possible_pos:
            possible_sw = node.state[:]
            print('index swap = '+ str(i))
            possible_sw[blank] = possible_sw[i]
            possible_sw[i] = 8
            print('the child node is ' + str(possible_sw))
            queue.append(Node(possible_sw, node))
        
    while node.parent:
        solution.append(node.state.index(8))
        node = node.parent

    solution.reverse()
    print('moves list '+ str(solution))
    return solution
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight as well. This is my first time using Python so I am still learning about the function. Thank you! @trincot

Comment: I do have another question regarding implementing a visit check. Would I make another list that appends nodes and make an if statement and if visit how would I change nodes to expand?

Comment: You can make a tuple of the current state and add that to a set of states. You can then use the `in` operator to check whether a state is already in that set.  If you cannot make it work, then post it as a new question and provide all the information necessary to clarify what exactly the problem and question is.